# Filter RDD based values in array using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Using pypark (python3) I am trying to create and filter an RDD based elements of an array.

```
INCLUDE_CITIES = {'Philadephia','Buffalo','Syracuse'}
...
...
...
rddFiltered = sc.textFile(fileLocation).filter(lambda line: line in INCLUDE_STATIONS)

print (rddFiltered.take(10))
```

Only if I find cities from the array, do I want the content to be in the RDD. The above is not the right syntax, but I need some help. I would like to stick to RDD for now and not use Datasets or DF.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is an issue with your text file **or** perhaps you didnt put the text file in HDFS (use the command hdfs dfs -put cities.txt to place the text file in your HDFS Home directory)

This example works fine for me

1) Create a text file

cities.txt

```
Varun,23,Buffalo
Trump,29,Syracuse
Obama,91,Phili
```

2) Place the text file in hdfs

```
hdfs dfs -put cities.txt
```

2) Run code

```
cities = {'Philadephia','Buffalo','Syracuse'}
cities_from_file = sc.textFile("cities.txt").map(lambda line: line.split(",")[2]).filter(lambda city: city in cities)
cities_from_file.take(5)

[u'Buffalo', u'Syracuse']
```

Comment: sorry @vi_ral. I am not using HDFS. This is on a stand-alone EC2 instance with Spark and Hadoop.

Comment: one more thing, the input text file is a comma delimited row of data. The cities are in column 6. So, I want only those records/rows that have values from the array in column 6.

Comment: I edited my code, I only included three columns for simplicity take. Edit this code so it gets data from the 6th column. Also mark this as the correct answer if this works. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. That's Awesome.